# sort tibble rows by descending count of NAs

Tags: r, sorting, tibble

Apologies if I have missed where this has been asked before - I couldn't find it. I am learning about tibbles and the verb `arrange`. I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to `arrange` rows in descending order of total row NA count then I have done below? I am using the `nycflights13` dataset.

```
library(nycflights13)
library(tidyverse)

options(tibble.width = Inf)
flights$na_count <- flights %>% is.na %>% rowSums
arrange(flights, desc(na_count))
```

Part of result:

[image]

I checked the help centre and this appears to be on topic though I know working code is often a candidate for code review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure whether much more efficient, however, you can rewrite it into:

```
flights %>% 
 arrange(desc(rowSums(is.na(.))))
```

Comment: Here's a base equivalent: ```flights[order(-xtfrm(rowSums(is.na(flights)))),]```. ```desc``` is equivalent to ```-xtfrm```.

Comment: Base R approaches can be found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24093446/sort-data-by-number-of-nas-in-each-line too @Cole

Comment: Thanks - note the link is for the default increasing. However, I forgot that ```order()``` has a ```decreasing``` argument: ```flights[order(rowSums(is.na(flights)), decreasing = T), ]```

Comment: @Cole Thanks for the interesting additional info.